# What happens when import modules in python?

Tags: python, import, module, initialization, package

I want to know really what happens when we import a module file in python.I mean it's process, in other words what things by python will be run or check?! like `__init__.py` or sys.modules and etc.
for example i know `__init__.py` are necessary files in every package,i want to know python what does with these files on import time?
please light this for me.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Read the [tutorial section about modules](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html), the documentation of the [import statement](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#import), the [`imp` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/imp.html) (particularly the examples) and maybe the docs for the [`__import__` builtin](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#__import__). That should get you a long way. If you still want to know more, I'd suggest to ask a specific question, this one is a bit on the broad side.

**Edit**: After reading your question once more, there is a specific part to your question, about what `__init__.py` does in packages. It basically can be empty or contain initialization code that will be executed when that package is imported. See the [section about packages](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#packages) for details.

In an `__init__.py` you could also set `__all__`, which defines what symbols get imported when you do `from yourpackage import *`. This is explained in detail in [importing * from a package](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#importing-from-a-package).

Comment: Thanks Lukas! for now i understood when we import a module, python search it in built-in modules first,if it can't find it there, python search it as .py module in sys.path, ok? i want to know when python found this module for example in our package, what it does with /__init__.py file? when it's an empty file what python does? what kind codes we can put in this file? can you show it with example? Thank you

Comment: @Deniz `__init__.py` just gets executed like any other module when you import the package. You can do anything you want in it, just like in any other Python module. If it's empty, it's function is simply as a marker file to distinguish Python packages from regular directories.